# apacite and local language translations

Tags: languages, apa-style

Is there an easy way to change a few things regarding `apacite` package? I'm particularly looking at the url reference. When compiled `apacite` says "Retrieved from" but I'd like it to be "Sótt þann" and also when referring to a book or an article it always says "&" between authors but I'd like it to be "og". Basically small things like that are in my way of using LaTeX for writing with citation in APA style. Would really like your help regarding this matter.

Comment: Did you try to use biblatex?  There exists a `biblatex-apa` package, biblatex understands babel and polyglossia and has many language modules (in particular icelandic). Moreover, it is easily customisable. Basically, in your examples, it would be as simple matter  as writing: `\DeclareBiblographyStrings{...}` in your preamble. Let me add that biber (to be preferred to bibtex in your case) understands utf8.

Comment: ok I´ve located the english.apc file and have made some changes in that file so that it is useable but I would still like to make more changes so it would fit the Icelandi APA style. Any ideas?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. Actually, I never used apacite and have been working only with biblatex for the last few years.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you see in english.apc, you can do in your own document:

`\renewcommand{\BBAA}{og}
\renewcommand{\BRetrievedFrom}{Sótt þan}`